# What should I do if I didnt get exiting stamp from USA inspector when I was leaving USA? MY VISA B1

Tags: usa, passport-stamps, i-94

I was in Hawaii for some days,  I got stamp customs when I arrived, but when I was leaving I didn't get any stamp, and I noticed when I was at home. I always got two stamps  from other countries. Now I am worry, I am in trouble. What I should do? Is that a problem when I will enter next time? How can I get exiting stamp? My visa is B1.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, **you actually didn't even see any CBP official when you exited the US by air**: the US has no exit controls in this situation (the only officials you saw were TSA, but they only check you don't carry anything dangerous and vaguely that you are the person matching the ID you present — they have nothing to do with immigration, passport control or customs), so nobody could have stamped your passport.

However, **the airline will have sent details of your exit to CBP electronically**, and they will have updated their records.

You can check the status of your record (called an I-94) on the official [I-94 website of CBP](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/).

If your record doesn't show you as having left (which is rare, but can happen), then you do indeed need to clarify this. You should find instructions and contact information for this on the same site.

Note that the situation would have been different if you had left the US by land (to Canada or Mexico, by road or rail or even on foot). In this case, you do indeed need to make sure your exit is recorded when you exit.

Comment: I wonder if you could go to any US embassy outside the USA and ask them to stamp your passport - as incontrovertible evidence that you must have left the USA.

Comment: @gnasher729 As far as I know, this procedures is only used in voluntary departure cases (where someone agrees to leave at their own expense to avoid deportation). In those cases, people are sometimes required to turn in a form at the embassy to be sent back to ICE. Otherwise, I don't believe embassies have any stamp that would be appropriate to place in passports for proof of exit. They are not immigration agents and cannot use CBP stamps.